# why is my c program scanning more inputs than the specified number?

Tags: c, visual-c++

If \n is not there the program accepts 5 and if \n is used in scanning then the programs asks for 6 inputs.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int marks[5];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d\n",&marks[i]);

    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("the element at    %d is  %d\n",i,marks[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Way too many tags. What language are you using? C/C++ is not a programming language.

Comment: Trailing newline in format string is bad. Remove it. This is a duplicate.

Comment: `\n` in the `scanf()` causing to wait for extra input. remove it.  `scanf("%d\n",&marks[i]);` -> `scanf("%d",&marks[i]);`